# How to prevent modal QDialog blocking mouse events in QCompleter?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDialog that has a QLineEdit with completer. It works fine when the dialog displayed non-modally (with `show()`), but when displayed with `exec()` mouse events to completer popup get intercepted or something (I hear the angry OS beep sound as if I am trying to click outside of the modal dialog).

Here is the sample code in the dialog constructor:

```cpp
QStringList user_list;
user_list << "Tom" << "Jerry" << "John" << "Jack" << "Bob" << "Bobby" << "Amir" << "James" << "Carl";
auto completer_model = new QStringListModel(this);
completer_model->setStringList(user_list);

auto completer = new QCompleter(completer_model, this);
completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
test_input->setCompleter(completer);
```

Comment: You get the beep when you click on the completer popup or outside of it? And what OS are you on? and which Qt version?

Comment: I am on MacOS qt 5.6. I get beep when I click on completer popup. Also scrollwheel isn't working.

Comment: I'm on KDE Neon, with Qt 6.5.0, and I cannot reproduce this, everything works fine with `exec`. You could use an event filter to investigate this further, install it on your objects one by one, and make it tell you what events got triggered, something like `qDebug()<<object<<event->type();`.

Comment: You might also want to minimize the example further, do everything in one file (`main.cpp` for example), the `QDialog` and the `QLineEdit` and the `QCompleter`. Test this on a `QComboBox` as well, see if it's the dialog being modal messing with every popup, or just the `QCompleter`.